# if $ x \equiv y \pmod{4}$ then $n^x \equiv n^y \pmod{10} $

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If  $x \equiv y \pmod{4}$ then  $n^x \equiv n^y \pmod{10} x,y$ and $n$ are intergers.
I know that:
Since $x \equiv y \pmod{4}$ we have $4|x-y \Rightarrow n^4|n^{x-y}$. 
$n^x-n^y = n^y( n^{x-y}-1)$

Comment: Note that $\phi(10)=4$.

Comment: See the [Theorem & Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe (using $e=ϕ(m)$)
 & Euler's Theorem).  Here $\,m=10\,$ so  $\,\phi(m) = 4\ \ $

Comment: Certainly not true if $x=0,y=4, n=2$  It doesn't even make sense if $x$ or $y$ is negative. But true if $x,y$ are positive integers.